# Drop or modify consecutive duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Suppose we have a DataFrame with two types of data: `float` and `ndarray` (shape is always `(2,)`):

```py
data = [
    0.1, np.array([1.0, 0.1]), np.array([1.0, 0.1]),
    np.array([1.0, 0.1]), 0.1, 0.1, np.array([0.1, 1.0]), 1.0
]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': data,}, index=[0., 1., 2.0, 2.6, 3., 3.2, 3.4, 4.0]
)
```

```
x   | A
----|-------------
0.0 | 1.0
1.0 | [1.0, 0.1]
2.0 | [1.0, 0.1]
2.6 | [1.0, 0.1]
3.0 | 0.1
3.2 | 0.1
3.4 | [0.1, 1.0]
4.0 | 1.0
```

I would like to process consecutive duplicates in order to:

1. Drop repetitions if they are `float`s (keeping the first in the "group");
2. Modifying each element in the "group" using **all** index values **this group** if these elements are `ndarray`s.

The expected result for a given example would be something like (here I tried to proportionally split the range `[1., 0.1]` onto three regions):

```
x   | A
----|-------------
0.0 | 1.0
1.0 | [1.0, 0.55]
2.0 | [0.55, 0.28]
2.6 | [0.28, 0.1]
3.0 | 0.1
3.4 | [0.1, 1.0]
4.0 | 1.0
```

To start with, I've tried using `df != df.shift()` to find duplicates, but it would raise an error when coparisng `float` with `ndarry` and would not "group" more than 2 elements.

I was also trying to `groupby(by=function)`, where function is checking the dtype of the element, but it seems that `groupby` is acting ony on index in this case.

Obviously, I can loop through rows and keep track of repetitions, but it is not very elegant (efficient).

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What is the rule that you change *[1.0, 0.1]* into *[1.0, 0.55]* (values for index == *1.0*)? The same question for 2 following rows.

Comment: Well, it is not really important here (any rule will do for the sake of example). Here I was trying to `split` the range `[1.0, 0.1]` proportionally.

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1: Drop consecutive equal floats

To check whether 2 elements of a row are equal floats, define
the following function:

```
def equalFloats(row):
    if (type(row.A).__name__ == 'float') and (type(row.B).__name__ == 'float'):
        return row.A == row.B
    return False
```

Then, temporarily add to *df* column *B* containing the previous value
in *A* column:

```
df['B'] = df.A.shift()
```

And to drop consecutive floats in *A* column (and also drop
*B* column) run:

```
df = df[~df.apply(equalFloats, axis=1)][['A']]
```

For the time being *df* contains:

```
              A
0.0         0.1
1.0  [1.0, 0.1]
2.0  [1.0, 0.1]
2.6  [1.0, 0.1]
3.0         0.1
3.4  [0.1, 1.0]
4.0           1
4.5         2.1
```

To check that consecutive, but different floats are not removed,
I added row with index *4.5* and value *2.1*. As you see, it was not removed.

## Step 2: Convert arrays in *A* column

Define another function:

```
def step2(row):
    if type(row.A).__name__ == 'ndarray':
        arr = row.A
        arr[1] = arr.sum() / row.name
        return row
    return row
```

(*row.name* is the index value of the current row).

Then apply it:

```
df = df.apply(step2, axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
                              A
0.0                         0.1
1.0                  [1.0, 2.1]
2.0                [1.0, 0.775]
2.6   [1.0, 0.5473372781065089]
3.0                         0.1
3.4  [0.1, 0.12456747404844293]
4.0                           1
4.5                         2.1
```

If you want, change the formula in *step2* to any other of your choice.

## Edit following comments

I defined *df* as:

```
              A
0.0         0.1
1.0  [1.0, 0.1]
2.0  [1.0, 0.1]
2.6  [1.0, 0.1]
3.0         0.1
3.1         0.1
3.2         0.1
3.4  [0.1, 1.0]
4.0           1
4.5         2.1
```

It contains **3** consecutive *0.1* values.
Note that you didn't write about **how many** consecutive
values contains such a "group".

Both functions can be defined also with *isinstance*:

```
def equalFloats(row):
    if isinstance(row.A, float) and isinstance(row.B, float):
        return row.A == row.B
    return False

def step2(row):
    if isinstance(row.A, np.ndarray):
        arr = row.A
        arr[1] = arr.sum() / row.name
        return row
    return row
```

Then after you run:

```
df['B'] = df.A.shift()
df = df[~df.apply(equalFloats, axis=1)][['A']]
df = df.apply(step2, axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
                             A
0.0                        0.1
1.0                 [1.0, 1.1]
2.0                [1.0, 0.55]
2.6  [1.0, 0.4230769230769231]
3.0                        0.1
3.4  [0.1, 0.3235294117647059]
4.0                          1
4.5                        2.1
```

As you can see, from a sequence of 3 values of *0.1* remained
only the first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I like the idea of treating different `dtype`s separately. However, your answer is missing an important point in the step2: treating consecutive duplicates together because values should depend on: 1) number of repetitions; 2) index values (or more precisely the range of index values).

Comment: Also, why have you choose to `.__name__ == 'float'` over the `isinstance(x, float)`?